# How to install GITLAB local server on MACOS?

Tags: macos, gitlab

I switched from Ubuntu to MAC OS and i want to setup a local GITLAB server Community Edition on my MAC OS local system.
Is there any documentation or tutorial which can guide with step by step process to install GITLAB on local machine from command terminal?

Answer (score 1):

The best option (only option, really) for MacOS would be to use [the docker installation method](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html) or helm/kubernetes.

The only other supported/tested [installation methods](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/) are for Linux (specifically, Debian-based distributions of Linux). There is no native support or testing for running GitLab directly on MacOS without docker/k8s.